# How to quietly install LDAP on Ubuntu client

Tags: configuration, apt, debconf

I'd like to install libpam-ldap to use ldap on a client machine and I was hoping to use

```
sudo apt-get install -qq libpam-ldap
```

to quietly install the package as part of a bash script used to configure a client once Ubuntu installs. However it still comes up with a blue screen GUI asking for configuration information. Since I intend to just copy an existing `/etc/ldap.conf` file to overwrite the auto generated one I'd like to skip that step but don't know how.

How do you install a package and make it skip its interactive configuration stage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the debconf frontend to noninteractive:

```
 sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -qq libpam-ldap
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Also, before I use it on a none test environment, is there a way to get a list of all config files the command normally makes so that I can make sure to override them? (The reason I ask is that I think it creates another config files besides /etc/ldap.conf?)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a way to configure debconf for unattended operation.

In the [debconf manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man7/debconf.7.html) check out the section on "Unattended Package Installation". The same manpage has information about Priorities, which might let you be able to skip the question entirely.

I've set this up in the past with [Puppet and preseeds](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Debian_Preseed_Patterns) but it's been a long time, hopefully this will at least get you on the right track.

Comment: Cool thanks, I'm going to look into more about unattended installs.

Answer (score -1):

I write script for fast login in LDAP
http://itc-life.ru/skript-vvoda-debian-8-v-ldapdomen/

Comment: What if the link goes down  ? this won't be an answer anymore .. Please copy / paste important part from your link to this answer